# MongoDB + php. Установка времени жизни записи в коллекции MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

Дайте пожалуйста пример c пояснением, как кодом php установить документ или поле документа, которое самоудалится через 1 минуту после добавления. Не пойму я буржуйские инструкции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вроде разобрался, сначала нам нужно коллекции индекс поставить, а потом можем документы в ее добавлять и таймер устанавливать на каждый документ.

```
$coll_obyav->ensureIndex(array(
    'expireAt' => 1,
    ), array(
    'background' => true,
    'name' => 'TTL',
    'expireAfterSeconds' => 0,
 ));

$key='1';
$expire=30;

$coll_obyav->update(array(
        'key' => $key
     ), array(
          'key' => $key,
          'expireAt' => new MongoDate(time() + $expire)
     ), array(
          'upsert' => true
     ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот ссылка на ответ, который подходит под Ваш случай:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817416/mongodb-php-use-a-ttl-with-ensureindex

**Вот перевод содержания:**

Автор вопроса хочет удалять каждое сообщение из базы спустя 30 сек. после добавления.
Приводит пример кода:

```
$mess = array(
    "login" => $_SESSION['name'],
    "message" => $_POST['msg'],
    "expire" => true
);

$db->chat->insert($mess);
$collection = $db->chat;
$collection->ensureIndex(array('expire' => true), array('expireAfterSeconds' => 30));
```

Автор ответа:

*Не знаком с деталями синтаксиса PHP, но поле `expired` должно принимать значение `DateTime`, а не boolean. Например, вы можете приравнять `expired` к текущему времени и полагаться на 30с в `expireAfterSeconds`. Другой, более гибкий вариант: установить `expire` значение текущще время +30сек. (это позволит регулировать значения таймаута для каждого отдельного документа).*

Далее автор ответа замечает, что не стоит рассчитывать, что TTL функции будут отрабатывать с точностью до секунды. Если необходима высокая точность времени отработки для записей с очень коротким сроком жизни, стоит обратить внимание на *capped collections* и *tailable cursors*, как альтернативу TTL функциям.